# SQL Server - Regex pattern match only alphanumeric characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an nvarchar(50) column `myCol` with values like these 16-digit, alphanumeric values, starting with '0':
`0b00d60b8d6cfb19, 0b00d60b8d6cfb05, 0b00d60b8d57a2b9`

I am trying to delete rows with `myCol` values that don't match those 3 criteria.

By following [this article](https://www.sqlshack.com/t-sql-regex-commands-in-sql-server/), I was able to select the records starting with '0'. However, despite the `[a-z0-9]` part of the regex, it also keeps selecting `myCol` values containing special characters like `00-d@!b8-d6/f&#b`. Below is my select query:

```
SELECT * from Table
WHERE myCol LIKE '[0][a-z0-9]%' AND LEN(myCol) = 16
```

How should the expression be changed to select only rows with `myCol` values that don't contain special characters?

Comment: What counts as a "special character"? Also do you mean to have `AND LEN(myCol) = 16` in your `LIKE` pattern? If not, if not, then there's your problem.

Comment: Thanks, added length check. Special character = any character that is not alphanumeric.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the value must only contain a-z and digits, and must start with a `0` you could use the following:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES(N'0b00d60b8d6cfb19'),
            (N'0b00d60b8d6cfb05'),
            (N'0b00d60b8d57a2b9'),
            (N'00-d@!b8-d6/f&#b'))V(myCol)
WHERE V.myCol LIKE '0%' --Checks starts with a 0
  AND V.myCol NOT LIKE '%[^0-9A-z]%' --Checks only contains alphanumerical characters
  AND LEN(V.myCol) = 16;
```

The second clause works as the `LIKE` will match any character that *isn't* an alphanumerical character. The `NOT` then (obviously) reverses that, meaning that the expression only resolves to TRUE when the value *only* contains alphanumerical characters.

Comment: Leaving mine because it works, but this is better than my answer

Answer (score 3):

Pattern matching in SQL Server is not awesome, and there is currently no real regex support.

The `%` in your pattern is what is including the special characters you show in your example.  The `[a-z0-9]` is only matching a single character.  If your character lengths are 16 and you're only interested in letters and numbers then you can include a pattern for each one:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE myCol LIKE '[0][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9][a-z0-9]';
```

Note: you don't need the `AND LEN(myCol) = 16` with this.

Comment: This is nice, because it's instructive, but you're right that Larnu's is a skosh more elegant. +1 for both.